# Split Multiple Rasters into multiple rasters of different size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, splitting

I am wondering if there is a way to take multiple .tiff or .ecw files of any given size, and divide them up into multiple files of the same type, but of different size, using QGIS.

Also, is it is possible to do it by degrees, rather than "rows" and "columns"?

For example, say I have aerial imagery of a given region in the world. The total imagery is 10 degree by 10 degrees (lat/lon), but is divided into 4 equal quadrant images. Now say I want it to be divided into 1x1 degree (lat/lon) blocks. It would go from 4 image files (2x2) to 100 (10x10).

It seems like I could do this manually by first merging the rasters as explained [here](https://support.dronesmadeeasy.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003641246-QGIS-Raster-Merging), then simply adding that single large raster to the canvas as selecting Save As and using the VRT Tile option as explained [here](https://howtoinqgis.wordpress.com/2016/12/17/how-to-split-a-raster-in-several-tiles-using-qgis-or-python-gdal/) to split it. I tried to use the merge capability to do this, but my PC locked up for hours. I couldn't move anything and ended up just hard powering it off. There was a very small corrupt file that I just trashed, so it didn't seem to get far.

My question is, do you even need to do the merge. Can you split multiple files? If not, I might just write a new plugin that will.